# how to uniquely concatenate a value in mysql for a non key field

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, concatenation

I'm using a third party mysql table (ie I can't change any of its properties) and I have a row that has id (key), name and value.

I want to store unique cache keys into a row with the name cacheKeys.. and this is my sql statement

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." (name, value) VALUES ('CacheKeys', '".$key."') ON
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = CONCAT_WS (',', $tableName.value, '$key')";
```

I've already implemented my caching algorithm, so that every time someone adds a cache key, I check to see if it already exists (from the CacheKeys row above), if it does I fetch it from cache.. otherwise I store it.

Problem is it seems that the sql write operation takes time, and it often stores duplicate cacheKeys 
ie: currencies,defaultCurrencyId,user19,currency1,currency1,currency1,currency1,currency1

So I need to check to see that I'm not adding a duplicate key into the cacheKeys field.. and I need to do that using SQL (using php, ie regex etc would just be waaaay to expensive).

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
 INSERT INTO tb (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Jack', 'Doe') IF NOT  
 EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tb WHERE firstname='Jack' AND lastname='Doe' );
```

Comment: this does not answer my question.. there is no unique string concatenation involved in your answer